# Message sent to deallocated instance which has never been released

Tags: iphone, concurrency

I started dealing with NSOperations and (as usual with concurrency) I'm observing strange behaviour.
In my class I've got an instance variable:

```
    NSMutableArray *postResultsArray;
```

when one button in the UI is pressed I initialize the array:

```
postResultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and setup the operations (together with dependencies).

In the operations I create a custom object and try to add to the array:

```
PostResult *result = [[PostResult alloc] initWithServiceName:@"Sth" andResult:someResult];
[self.postResultsArray addObject:result];
```

and while adding I get:

> -[CFArray retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3b40c30

which is strange as I don't release the array anywhere in my code (I did, but when the problem started to appear I commented all the release operations to be sure that they are not the case). I also used to have @synchronized section like below:

```
PostResult *result = [[PostResult alloc] initWithServiceName:@"Sth" andResult:someResult];
    @synchronized (self.postResultsArray) {
        [self.postResultsArray addObject:result];
    }
```

but the problem was the same (however, the error was for the synchronized operation).

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
postResultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

`[NSMutableArray array]` is a convient method which is equivalent to `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]`. So there is an implicit (auto)release there. Since you're going to keep it, you have to use one of these 3 changes:

1. ```
   postResultsArray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
   ```
2. ```
   postResultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   ```
3. Exploit the fact that a setter should retain the new value (if you declare as `@property(retain)`):

   ```
   self.postResultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
   ```